# How do I make the text in this link bold?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit Me", "Edit", new { id=item.ID })
```

In the above example, how do I make "Edit Me" bold? I tried placing `<b></b>` around the text but the bold tags are displayed literally. Instead of "Edit Me", the link displays "`<b>`Edit Me`</b>`".

Thanks!

PS - I'm using the MVC 4 beta but I don't see a tag that is that specific.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is using the style attribute like:

`@Html.ActionLink("Edit Me", "Edit", new { id=item.ID, style="font-weight:bold;" })`

or you can set a class which you define in your css to be bold

`@Html.ActionLink("Edit Me", "Edit", new { id=item.ID, @class="yourBoldClass" })`

CSS: `.yourBoldClass { font-weight: bold; }`

Comment: @class= would work, class is a reserved keyword and can not be used as a field name.

Comment: Fredrik C: good answer but can you update your sample to use [at]class as Peter points out. I would rewrite this as 1: the preferred way is via css using @class or (list 2nd) the easiest way using style directly

Answer (score 3):

I dont usually apply styles to an ACtionLink method because i think it is not a clean approach. Instead i will use a css class and define my style there and use that it in my link like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit Me", "Edit","yourControllerName", new { id=item.ID },new {@class="yourClassName"})
```

and have a css class like this

```
.yourClassName
{
  font-weight:bold;

}
```

you are using this constructor here

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

Here is the documentation : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can just put your url between <b></b>  like that:

```
<b> @Html.ActionLink("Edit Me", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) </b>
```

but the version with css is better

Answer (score 1):

You cannot insert html in the link text with `Html.ActionLink`.

Write the `<a>` "by hand" (or create a new helper):

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new { id=item.ID })"><b>"Edit Me"</b></a>
```

Or add a class to the link and do the "bolding" with CSS.